# Logcat filtering?

Tags: android

I'd like to filter out everything from the log, except for my app's processes. I know that I can specify priority levels, but I want to be able to do more than that. I wanna get rid of all the other stuff that's going on in the phone that's being logged. How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're viewing the logs in the Eclipse debug view, you can do this very easily by just clicking the Create Filter button (green + sign).

If not using Eclipse, specify the filter on the command line as follows (example from the Android docs):

> Here's an example of a filter expression that suppresses all log messages except those with the tag "ActivityManager", at priority "Info" or above, and all log messages with tag "MyApp", with priority "Debug" or above:
>
> ```
> adb logcat ActivityManager:I MyApp:D *:S
> ```

Comment: Not using Eclipse ;) Running ADB in the terminal. I find it's easier if I have it running separately.

Comment: @LuxuryMode: adb explanation added

Comment: Thanks Graham. When I do that, all I see is `--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main` Is that because I don't have log tags in my app? I'd like to be able to see only my app's processes without having to add tags to every activity or whatever. Is there some easy way to define a tag for the entire app, if that makes any sense?

Comment: The tag is whatever you pass as the first parameter to the Log function. There is no extra option for a per-app tag.

Comment: Ok, then I know I can just filter out specific stuff that shows up a lot in the log, such as GSMDataConnection. I've done it before, but can't remember how...

Comment: The "*:S" is important to silent all others outputs! E.g to see ONLY "console.log()" output from chromium, i use `adb logcat "*:S" "chromium" `.

Answer (score 1):

Yes now you will get it automatically....
Update to [ADT plugin version 14](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html), where the logcat will automatic `session filter`
where it filter log in you specific app (package)

Answer (score 0):

Filtering logcat via command line can be done by setting a text string to silent, like  `WifiStatetracker:S` . This will get rid of anything with WifiStateTracker in it.  You can use multiple arguments, like `WifiStatetracker:S dhcpcd:S BatteryService:S`.  I don't know how the matching scheme works, though.