# Android App with libgdx is pushed to the background after a while

Tags: java, android, crash, libgdx, android-logcat

*I decided to retype the question since i gain more insight into the problem:*

Hi,
I am quite despaired! Please help me! I invested so much time in this app and can't find the solution to this bug since 2 weeks!

App description:
I developed an app for android with the LibGdx engine. It's a jump and run game. Hereby Box2d is modeling the physic, a tiled map is rendered, a object parser is creating the objects, all data is managed with the asset manager, a stage which contains tables for the menu/HUD - ask for more detail if necessary!

Problem description (The bug is only (!) occurring on real devices (yes - I tried more then one device)):
After playing some levels the app is suddenly pushed to the background without any notification or something. After resuming the app via the task manager the app restarts. This happen randomly after a couple of minutes.

Logcat-output in "API-USB-Debug-mode":

No specific error for the app-pid when the app crashes - ask if your are still interested in!

This system-wide output always occur a couple of seconds before the crash occurs:

```
01-29 21:07:51.915: W/InputDispatcher(2345): channel '421c2b38 com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
01-29 21:07:51.915: E/InputDispatcher(2345): channel '421c2b38 com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
01-29 21:07:51.915: I/WindowState(2345): WIN DEATH: Window{421c2b38 u0 com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher}
01-29 21:07:51.920: W/InputDispatcher(2345): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '421c2b38 com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher (server)'
```

After the this lines the app always crash and the following lines are printed:

```
01-29 21:07:56.290: I/ActivityManager(2345): Process com.google.process.location (pid 18862) has died.
01-29 21:07:56.300: I/ActivityManager(2345): Process com.facebook.katana (pid 19483) has died.
01-29 21:08:05.035: D/lights(2345): set_light_buttons: 1
01-29 21:08:08.800: I/ActivityManager(2345): Process com.android.inputmethod.latin (pid 18611) has died.
01-29 21:08:08.815: W/InputMethodManagerService(2345): Session failed to close due to remote exception
01-29 21:08:08.815: W/InputMethodManagerService(2345): android.os.DeadObjectException
01-29 21:08:08.815: W/InputMethodManagerService(2345):  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
01-29 21:08:08.815: W/InputMethodManagerService(2345):  at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy.finishSession(IInputMethodSession.java:292)
01-29 21:08:08.815: W/InputMethodManagerService(2345):  at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.finishSessionLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1373)
01-29 21:08:08.815: W/InputMethodManagerService(2345):  at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.clearClientSessionLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1364)
01-29 21:08:08.815: W/InputMethodManagerService(2345):  at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.clearCurMethodLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1390)
01-29 21:08:08.815: W/InputMethodManagerService(2345):  at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.onServiceDisconnected(InputMethodManagerService.java:1409)
01-29 21:08:08.815: W/InputMethodManagerService(2345):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1115)
01-29 21:08:08.815: W/InputMethodManagerService(2345):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1129)
01-29 21:08:08.815: W/InputMethodManagerService(2345):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-29 21:08:08.815: W/InputMethodManagerService(2345):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-29 21:08:08.815: W/InputMethodManagerService(2345):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-29 21:08:08.815: W/InputMethodManagerService(2345):  at com.android.server.ServerThread.initAndLoop(SystemServer.java:1223)
01-29 21:08:08.815: W/InputMethodManagerService(2345):  at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:1309)
01-29 21:08:08.815: W/InputMethodManagerService(2345):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 21:08:08.815: W/InputMethodManagerService(2345):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-29 21:08:08.815: W/InputMethodManagerService(2345):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
01-29 21:08:08.815: W/InputMethodManagerService(2345):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-29 21:08:08.815: W/InputMethodManagerService(2345):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-29 21:08:10.040: D/lights(2345): set_light_buttons: 2
01-29 21:08:15.270: D/lights(2345): set_light_buttons: 1
01-29 21:08:20.275: D/lights(2345): set_light_buttons: 2
01-29 21:08:21.560: I/ActivityManager(2345): Process archenoah.bounce (pid 19251) has died.
01-29 21:08:21.560: W/ActivityManager(2345): Force removing ActivityRecord{41fe9cb8 u0 archenoah.bounce/.MainActivity t233}: app died, no saved state
01-29 21:08:21.565: I/WindowState(2345): WIN DEATH: Window{41f9f330 u0 archenoah.bounce/archenoah.bounce.MainActivity}
01-29 21:08:21.580: I/OMXNodeInstance(1907): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x400e3798 successful
01-29 21:08:21.580: I/OMXNodeInstance(1907): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x400e4278 successful
01-29 21:08:21.580: I/OMXNodeInstance(1907): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x400e41a8 successful
01-29 21:08:21.580: I/OMXNodeInstance(1907): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x40cca488 successful
01-29 21:08:21.580: I/OMXNodeInstance(1907): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x40cca3d8 successful
01-29 21:08:21.590: I/OMXNodeInstance(1907): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x40cca2b0 successful
01-29 21:08:21.590: I/OMXNodeInstance(1907): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x400e3130 successful
01-29 21:08:21.590: I/OMXNodeInstance(1907): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x4007ae78 successful
01-29 21:08:21.595: I/OMXNodeInstance(1907): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x41192a88 successful
01-29 21:08:21.595: I/OMXNodeInstance(1907): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x411929d0 successful
01-29 21:08:21.595: I/OMXNodeInstance(1907): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x41192900 successful
01-29 21:08:21.595: I/OMXNodeInstance(1907): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x40dd8d18 successful
01-29 21:08:21.595: I/OMXNodeInstance(1907): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x40fd9ba0 successful
01-29 21:08:21.595: I/OMXNodeInstance(1907): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x40fd9a78 successful
01-29 21:08:21.595: I/OMXNodeInstance(1907): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x41192e20 successful
01-29 21:08:21.595: I/OMXNodeInstance(1907): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0x41192c10 successful
01-29 21:08:21.595: W/WindowManager(2345): Force-removing child win Window{41fa6e20 u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{41f9f330 u0 archenoah.bounce/archenoah.bounce.MainActivity}
01-29 21:08:21.620: W/WindowManager(2345): Failed looking up window
01-29 21:08:21.620: W/WindowManager(2345): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@41fd0e58 does not exist
01-29 21:08:21.620: W/WindowManager(2345):  at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7965)
01-29 21:08:21.620: W/WindowManager(2345):  at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7956)
01-29 21:08:21.620: W/WindowManager(2345):  at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:1047)
01-29 21:08:21.620: W/WindowManager(2345):  at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:493)
01-29 21:08:21.620: W/WindowManager(2345):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
01-29 21:08:21.625: I/WindowState(2345): WIN DEATH: null
01-29 21:08:21.665: I/ActivityManager(2345): Start proc com.android.launcher3 for activity com.android.launcher3/.Launcher: pid=19692 uid=10110 gids={50110, 1028}
01-29 21:08:22.710: I/ActivityManager(2345): Config changes=480 {1.0 262mcc1mnc en_GB ldltr sw360dp w360dp h615dp 320dpi nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.152 themeResource=null}
01-29 21:08:22.725: I/InputReader(2345): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
01-29 21:08:22.725: I/InputReader(2345): Device reconfigured: id=11, name='sec_touchscreen', size 720x1280, orientation 0, mode 1, display id 0
01-29 21:08:22.730: I/InputReader(2345): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
01-29 21:08:22.755: D/PhoneStatusBar(12447): mSettingsPanelGravity = 55
01-29 21:08:22.920: I/ActivityManager(2345): Start proc android.process.acore for content provider com.android.providers.contacts/.ContactsProvider2: pid=19705 uid=10001 gids={50001, 3003, 1028, 1015}
01-29 21:08:23.000: V/Launcher(19692): LauncherAppState inited
01-29 21:08:23.070: W/Launcher(19692): setApplicationContext called twice! old=com.android.launcher3.LauncherApplication@41f544d8 new=com.android.launcher3.LauncherApplication@41f544d8
01-29 21:08:23.305: I/DeviceProfile.render()(19692): Showing searchbar.
01-29 21:08:23.440: I/ContactLocale(19705): AddressBook Labels [en_GB]: [, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z, Α, Β, Γ, Δ, Ε, Ζ, Η, Θ, Ι, Κ, Λ, Μ, Ν, Ξ, Ο, Π, Ρ, Σ, Τ, Υ, Φ, Χ, Ψ, Ω, , А, Б, В, Г, Д, Е, Є, Ж, З, И, І, Ї, Й, К, Л, М, Н, О, П, Р, С, Т, У, Ф, Х, Ц, Ч, Ш, Щ, Ю, Я, , א, ב, ג, ד, ה, ו, ז, ח, ט, י, כ, ל, מ, נ, ס, ע, פ, צ, ק, ר, ש, ת, , ا, ب, ت, ث, ج, ح, خ, د, ذ, ر, ز, س, ش, ص, ض, ط, ظ, ع, غ, ف, ق, ك, ل, م, ن, ه, و, ي, , ก, ข, ฃ, ค, ฅ, ฆ, ง, จ, ฉ, ช, ซ, ฌ, ญ, ฎ, ฏ, ฐ, ฑ, ฒ, ณ, ด, ต, ถ, ท, ธ, น, บ, ป, ผ, ฝ, พ, ฟ, ภ, ม, ย, ร, ฤ, ล, ฦ, ว, ศ, ษ, ส, ห, ฬ, อ, ฮ, , ㄱ, ㄴ, ㄷ, ㄹ, ㅁ, ㅂ, ㅅ, ㅇ, ㅈ, ㅊ, ㅋ, ㅌ, ㅍ, ㅎ, , あ, か, さ, た, な, は, ま, や, ら, わ, #, ]
01-29 21:08:24.225: D/libEGL(19692): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
01-29 21:08:24.240: D/libEGL(19692): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
01-29 21:08:24.260: D/libEGL(19692): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
01-29 21:08:24.300: E/(19692): Device driver API match
01-29 21:08:24.300: E/(19692): Device driver API version: 23
01-29 21:08:24.300: E/(19692): User space API version: 23 
01-29 21:08:24.305: E/(19692): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Wed Oct  9 21:05:57 KST 2013 
01-29 21:08:24.465: D/OpenGLRenderer(19692): Enabling debug mode 0
01-29 21:08:24.540: I/ActivityManager(2345): Displayed com.android.launcher3/.Launcher: +2s891ms
01-29 21:08:24.540: I/ActivityManager(2345): Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{425d6958 u0 com.android.launcher3/.Launcher t1} time:107475229
01-29 21:08:24.605: W/InputMethodManagerService(2345): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 19251 uid 10131
01-29 21:08:24.625: D/LightsService(2345): Excessive delay setting light: 65ms
01-29 21:08:24.625: I/ActivityManager(2345): Start proc com.android.inputmethod.latin for service com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME: pid=19730 uid=10026 gids={50026, 1028, 1015}
01-29 21:08:24.625: V/InputMethodManagerService(2345): Adding window token: android.os.Binder@4231b288
01-29 21:08:24.675: I/ActivityManager(19692): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41f4eae0 time:107475364
01-29 21:08:24.785: I/LatinIME(19730): Hardware accelerated drawing: true
01-29 21:08:24.940: I/WindowManager(2345): Screen frozen for +3s198ms due to Window{42bb8230 u0 com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper}
01-29 21:08:24.950: W/InputAttributes(19730): No editor info for this field. Bug?
01-29 21:08:24.970: I/ResourceUtils(19730): Find override value: resource=keypress_vibration_durations build=[HARDWARE=smdk4x12 MODEL=GT-I9300 BRAND=samsung MANUFACTURER=samsung] override=8
01-29 21:08:24.970: I/ResourceUtils(19730): Found default value: resource=keypress_volumes build=[HARDWARE=smdk4x12 MODEL=GT-I9300 BRAND=samsung MANUFACTURER=samsung] default=-1.0f
01-29 21:08:24.990: I/LatinIME:LogUtils(19730): Dictionary info: dictionary = userunigram.de.dict ; version = ? ; date = ?
01-29 21:08:24.995: I/LatinIME:LogUtils(19730): Dictionary info: dictionary = UserHistoryDictionary.de.dict ; version = ? ; date = 1390835364
01-29 21:08:25.000: I/LatinIME:LogUtils(19730): Dictionary info: dictionary = personalization.de.dict ; version = ? ; date = 1390835364
01-29 21:08:25.000: I/LatinIME:LogUtils(19730): Dictionary info: dictionary = PersonalizationPredictionDictio ; version = ? ; date = 1390835364
01-29 21:08:25.030: V/RenderScript(19692): 0x5db8d108 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
01-29 21:08:25.035: I/LatinIME:LogUtils(19730): Dictionary info: dictionary = main:de ; version = 40 ; date = 1380519383
01-29 21:08:26.585: W/BackupManagerService(2345): dataChanged but no participant pkg='com.android.launcher3' uid=10110
01-29 21:08:26.595: W/BackupManagerService(2345): dataChanged but no participant pkg='com.android.launcher3' uid=10110
01-29 21:08:26.620: W/BackupManagerService(2345): dataChanged but no participant pkg='com.android.launcher3' uid=10110
01-29 21:08:26.635: W/BackupManagerService(2345): dataChanged but no participant pkg='com.android.launcher3' uid=10110
01-29 21:08:26.655: W/BackupManagerService(2345): dataChanged but no participant pkg='com.android.launcher3' uid=10110
01-29 21:10:43.550: D/LightsService(2345): Excessive delay setting light: 81ms
01-29 21:11:00.520: D/LightsService(2345): Excessive delay setting light: 65ms
```

Comment: A raw logcat has a lot of noise in it.  Which lines are from your app?  (What's its name and/or pid?)  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405422/logcat-filtering.  Does your game use an input device?  (On-screen keyboard?)  Any interesting settings?  Do you do any networking in your app?

Comment: Thank you! I edit the thread in regarding of the logcat-output! I don't use network, no on-screen keyboard or any interesting settings...

Comment: Are you sure the "Could not read parameter file at "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.touchtype.swiftkey/files/parameters.json" is completely unrelated? According to [this link](http://support.swiftkey.net/forums/116693-2-bug-reports/suggestions/4531749-keyboard-freezes-and-get-restarted) this is a SwiftKey problem that also seems to occur once in a while.

Comment: Thank You! Ye...I'm quite sure since the crashes also occur at the device of my brother which isn't using Swift Key...

Comment: The error message says Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel. Here are some links discussing similar error as yours:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564068/android-activity-dialog-dialog-disappears-unexpectedly

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6966/win-death-channel-is-unrecoverably-broken-and-will-be-disposed

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562161/app-crashes-on-android-4-0-but-not-2-3-strange-exception

Comment: I saw you have the same error message as me. Does anyone know the reason (or a solution) for 
Device driver API match
Device driver API version: 23
User space API version: 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the mistake...When I'm setting a tiled map dynamically after every level this lead to an error...Since i hadn't any specific exception, this error was very hard to find...I solved it with saving the maps in an array at the start and receive it during run time instead of recreating the map every time.

map.add(new TmxMapLoader().load("data/maps/menu.tmx"));

Do anyone know what the problem was?

Thanks for your help anyway!